# How do you give multi-stores different themes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, multistore

Under Stores/Different Stores I have set up a new website, store and store view. The new store has its own root category. I've set up the base urls to point the the second url. I've done the sym links etc. The URL now points correctly to the store but I cannot figure out how to set a different theme for my second store.

I go into Content/Design/Configuration and my new store is nowhere to be seen. I have no idea how to specify that I want a different theme for it.

Can anyone advise me?
[image: No second store in the content/design/configuration]

Comment: whats the status of new store view ? Check your new storeview status it must be enabled , if its enable then that new store view shows in Content/Design/Configuration here you can see your new store, then edit it and change the theme which you want to apply.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When new Website or store view created you have to run the following command in your commandline,

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Once this done, you can able to see your new store in design section to edit and set the custom theme.

Comment: worked for me!!

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)

Comment: its work for me

Comment: perfect answer +1